# Automatically creating events related to a new event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, events, automation

Does anyone know of an existing tool that will let you automatically create multiple events whenever a new event is added to a Google Calendar?

The use case is if you always have the same pre/post events related to a main event. e.g. My concert is on December 1st. 1 month before that I need to book a hotel and 10 days before the concert I need to schedule a practice.

I tried setting it up at [ifttt](http://ifttt.com), but the Google Calendar channel is too limited. I could write an app using the API to do it, but a pre-existing solution would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-/Post-events sound like project planning, which made me think of MS Project. Google found me the [Microsoft® Project to Google® Calendar tool](http://daball.github.com/Microsoft-Project-to-Google-Calendar/).

It's been a while since I used MS Project, but I'm pretty sure you can link events like the way you've suggested.

I'm pretty sure that other import/export ways are possible (e.g., export from MSProject to iCal, import to Google Calendar).

Comment: Too bad MS Project is too heavy of a solution for this. But project planning is probably the closest fit.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say so, but as of now, there is no way to achieve this.

Also, I have never heard of pre/post events or anything like that before.